# Pull the part number from an assembly drawing depending on the part in that assembly drawing the user selected (CATIA VBA)

Tags: vba, catia

I'm trying to write a VBA program for CATIA that generates a leader with the part number of the element in the drawing that the user clicks on (selects).

The macro is to be used in assembly drawings with lots of parts. The user should be able to click on the part in the drawing and the part number for that specific part should appear in the text by the leader.

There are two problems.

1. I have to provide a parameter for what the user can select.
   I don't think it can be "DrawingView" since the user needs to be able to select the individual parts in an assembly view.
2. Pulling the part number from that selection.
   Right now my code pulls the name of the file that generated the view. In this case this is also the part number, but the macro's main use would be an assembly drawings with a bunch of parts.

I tried "AnyObject" as the selection, but VBA just selects the view even if I click on different parts inside the view. I've spent a large amount of time looking at different objects, properties, and methods on https://catiadesign.org/_doc/V5Automation/generated/interfaces/_index/CAAHomeIdx.htm but I can't find anything that would manipulate information depending on what part of the view gets selected.

I think this may be possible because CATIA gives the part number of different parts in an assembly view if you hover the dimension tool over the part on the drawing. So CATIA can get that information somehow.

```vb
Sub CatMain()
    'Sets drawing doc as active doc and makes sure a drawing is open
    Dim draw_doc As DrawingDocument
    On Error Resume Next
    Set draw_doc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "A drawing must be open to run this macro"
        End
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim draw_sheets As DrawingSheets            'Create drawing sheets collection
    Set draw_sheets = draw_doc.Sheets           'Set the drawing sheets collection to be the collection for the drawing document
    Dim draw_sheet As DrawingSheet              'Create drawing sheet object
    Set draw_sheet = draw_sheets.ActiveSheet    'Makes that drawing sheet object the active sheet
    Dim draw_view As DrawingView                'Creates drawing view objec
    Dim draw_leaders As DrawingLeaders          'Creates drawing leaders collection
    Dim draw_leader As DrawingLeader            'Makes drawing leader object
    
    Dim selection_array(0)                      'Create array that stores the the types of things CATIA can select
    selection_array(0) = "DrawingView"          'Make drawing views be the only thing that can be selected
    Set selection_1 = draw_doc.Selection        'Set the selection object to select things in this drawing document
    'Enable CATIA to go into selection mode and let the user click on something to select it
    status = selection_1.SelectElement2(selection_array, "Select the View(s) to Re-link. DON'T FORGET TO CLICK 'FINISH' ON TOOLS PALETTE.", False)
    'If the user presses ctrl+z or cancels then we stop the program
    If status = "Undo" Or status = "Cancel" Then
        MsgBox "You have chosen to terminate this macro."
        End
    End If
    Set draw_view = selection_1.Item(1).Value   'The drawing view is set to be the value of the view that was selected
    
    Dim leader_pos_x, leader_pox_y As Double    '==\
    leader_pos_x = 20                           '===> Dimension and set leader position
    leader_pos_y = 20                           '==/
    'The name/part number of can be taken from the drawing view with the .GenerativeBehavior.Document.Name properties
    Dim part_number As String
    part_number = draw_view.GenerativeBehavior.Document.Name 'gets the name of the document that generated the drawing view
    part_number = Replace(part_number, "_", " ")
    Dim draw_texts As DrawingTexts              'Create drawing texts collection
    Set draw_texts = draw_sheet.Views.ActiveView 'Set the drawing texts to the avtive view
    Dim draw_text As DrawingText                'Make drawing text object
    'Set the drawing text and position we're goint to use for the leader
    Set draw_text = draw_view.Texts.Add(part_number, 30, 50)
    'Create the leader with x and y position relative to the drawing view
    Set draw_leader = draw_text.Leaders.Add(leader_pos_x, leader_pos_y)
    
    'MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you don't mind using balloons try them instead. They can give you PartNumbers, InstanceNames and of course numbering. You have to change the options for drawing balloons. Here is a screen

[image]

Then you create balloons with partnumbers like so [image]

Catia knowing the partnumber doesn't mean that it is available in the free api. I'm afraid that you can't go any deeper than the - draw_view.GenerativeBehavior.Document

Just try to record your actions in macro or insert object resolution and see what you can get.

[image]

I made once a similar program, which automates drawings. I read the parts in assembly get their coordinates and placed the partnumbers in the drawing based on the assembly part coordinates. Drawing and assembly share the same axis systems if you haven't noticed (the blue arrows is the origin of assembly in 3D). But this was a special case only for specific assembly and can't be used in general on random assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to actually use balloons like DJakub proposed, here is a little workaround.

The script calls Catia's balloon command via `CATIA.StartCommand` and waits until the user clicks somewhere. In particular, it waits until a new DrawingText has been added, gets its content and deletes it. I couldn't come up with a good error handling, but after 10 seconds the script will also exit the loop.

```
Set oView = CATIA.ActiveDocument.DrawingRoot.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView
numtexts = oView.Texts.Count

'Change ToolsOptions so that balloons will be created with PartNumbers
'(Hint from DJakub)
Set settingRepository1 = CATIA.SettingControllers.Item("DraftingOptions")
settingValueBeforeChange = settingRepository1.GetAttr("DrwBalloonAssocMod")
settingRepository1.PutAttr "DrwBalloonAssocMod", 2 'Balloon creation with PartNumber

'Start Catia's Balloon command
CATIA.StartCommand "Balloon"

'Wait until user clicks somewhere
'(DrawingText with PartNumber will be added from Balloon command)
tic = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    If oView.Texts.Count > numtexts Then
        'Get text and remove balloon
        Set oText = oView.Texts.Item(oView.Texts.Count)
        strPartNumber = oText.Text
        oView.Texts.Remove oView.Texts.Count
        
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    toc = Timer
Loop Until toc - tic > 10 'Exit loop after 10 seconds

'Exit Ballon command
SendKeys "{ESC}", True

'Reset setting to standard
settingRepository1.PutAttr "DrwBalloonAssocMod", settingValueBeforeChange
```

There are some cases you might want to handle

- What if the users manually exits the balloon command? A new DrawingText within 10 seconds will get deleted
- What if the user doesn't click on a GeneratedItem?
- This script only gets the PartNumber. You probably know how to do the rest. I didnt check, but I bet you can also get the clicked point from the leader of the temporary balloon.

Comment: Keep in mind, this only a workaround to use if you really want the PartNumber to be a DrawingText and you don't like the appearance of a balloon (without the circle)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vyndell and DJakub for the help! I implemented your answers into my program and it works well! Below is the code for creating the leader with the method Vyndell showed in his answer.

Notable changes:

CATIA.StartCommand "Select" is used so the user doesn't have to deal with the balloon creation box after they click on a generated item (part in drawing).

A check is used if the user clicks on a random spot in the drawing. The balloon defaults to creating a numbered balloon if a part is not chosen. So I had the code convert the part number to an integer. If there is not an error number the user mostly likely clicked on a random spot and the program ends. If there was an error the program continues.

The code for the program is below.

```
Sub CATMain()



'Sets drawing doc as active doc and makes sure a drawing is open
Dim draw_doc As DrawingDocument
On Error Resume Next
Set draw_doc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "A drawing must be open to run this macro"
    End
End If
On Error GoTo 0



'Brings up macro instructions. The false sets the modal to false aka code runs with out messing with the form
Leader_Gen_With_Pt_Num_Inst.Show (False)



'Sets the view to be the current active view in CATIA
Set oView = CATIA.ActiveDocument.DrawingRoot.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView
'Stores the number of text associated with a view
numtexts = oView.Texts.Count



'Change Tools-->Options-->Drafting-->Annotation and Dress-up-->Balloon Creation so
'that balloons will be created with PartNumbers. Thanks DJakub!
Set settingRepository1 = CATIA.SettingControllers.Item("DraftingOptions")       'Set the options selection to drafting options
settingValueBeforeChange = settingRepository1.GetAttr("DrwBalloonAssocMod")     'The original user settings
settingRepository1.PutAttr "DrwBalloonAssocMod", 2                              'Balloon creation with PartNumber



'Start Catia's Balloon command
CATIA.StartCommand "Balloon"



'Dimension positioning variables
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
'Create drawing leader object
Dim draw_leader As DrawingLeader



'Sets the starting time for the timer for the variable tic
tic = Timer

Do

    DoEvents
    'Goes into the if statment when a text object has been added
    If oView.Texts.Count > numtexts Then
    
        'Get most recently create text in a text object
        Set oText = oView.Texts.Item(oView.Texts.Count)
        'Set a leader object to be the leader created from the balloon
        Set draw_leader = oText.Leaders.Item(oText.Leaders.Count)
        'Store the position of the leader in the doubles x and y
        draw_leader.GetPoint i, x, y
        'Store the part number in the string strpartnumber
        strpartnumber = oText.Text
        'Deletes the most recent text. Also deletes the leader since the text is its parent
        oView.Texts.Remove oView.Texts.Count
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    'Sets the end time for the timer to the variable toc
    toc = Timer
    
    'Since toc is the start and tic is the end, then toc minus tic means the timer will go to 8 seconds
    If toc - tic = 8 Then
        MsgBox "Ending macro since eight seconds have passed"
        'Ends program
        End
    End If
    
Loop Until toc - tic > 8 'Exit loop after 8 seconds

'Exit Ballon command
SendKeys "{ESC}", True



'Setting the CATIA command to select makes it so the balloon creation box doesn't appear when the user clicks away
CATIA.StartCommand "Select"



'Returns the ballon settings to what the user originally had
settingRepository1.PutAttr "DrwBalloonAssocMod", settingValueBeforeChange 'Will want to put this at the end of the main program



Dim draw_sheets As DrawingSheets            'Create drawing sheets collection
Set draw_sheets = draw_doc.Sheets           'Set the drawing sheets collection to be the collection for the drawing document
Dim draw_sheet As DrawingSheet              'Create drawing sheet object
Set draw_sheet = draw_sheets.ActiveSheet    'Makes that drawing sheet object the active sheet
'Dim draw_view As DrawingView                'Creates drawing view objec
Dim draw_leaders As DrawingLeaders          'Creates drawing leaders collection



'When something that is not a part in a drawing is clicked on, a numbered balloon is created
'So we cast the part number as an integer. When an error happens we know the user did not click on a random spot so we create the leader
'When an error is not thrown the user didn't click on the part, so we end the program and tell them what went wrong.
Dim test_int As Integer
On Error Resume Next
test_int = CInt(strpartnumber)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim part_number As String
    'part_number stores the part number value of strpartnumber that we got from the balloon
    part_number = strpartnumber
    'Repalce underscores with spaces
    part_number = Replace(part_number, "_", " ")
    Dim draw_texts As DrawingTexts              'Create drawing texts collection
    Set draw_texts = draw_sheet.Views.ActiveView 'Set the drawing texts to the avtive view
    Dim draw_text As DrawingText                'Make drawing text object
    'Set the drawing text and position we're goint to use for the leader
    'The text is set 40 mm over and 40 mm up from the leader arrow
    Set draw_text = oView.Texts.Add(part_number, x + 40, y + 40)
    'Create the leader with x and y position relative to the drawing view
    Set draw_leader = draw_text.Leaders.Add(x, y)

Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    'The message box actually doesn't run, but this code keeps the leader from being created if the user clicked a random spot
    MsgBox "You may have selected an item that is not an assembly part, so the program did not pull the part number"
    'Hides opened form
    Leader_Gen_With_Pt_Num_Inst.Hide
    End
End If



'Hides form once code has ran
Leader_Gen_With_Pt_Num_Inst.Hide



End Sub
```